# Cómo obtener registros mayores o iguales a una semana?

Tags: mysql

Tengo un inconveniente ahora mismo, quiero eliminar registros ya que son muchos, entonces quiero obtener los registros que tengan más de una semana de antigüedad, he intentado, pero no he podido que me regrese esos datos, así tengo mi Sentencia:

**Ejemplo:**

```
SELECT post.ID, post.post_title AS TITULO_POST,
       term.name AS CATEGORIA, 
       post.post_date AS FECHA_PUBLICACION
  FROM wplt_posts post 
 INNER JOIN wplt_term_relationships tax ON tax.object_id = post.ID
 INNER JOIN wplt_terms term ON term.term_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
 WHERE term.slug = 'entrevistas' AND post.post_date >= NOW() + INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar con esto, gracias.

Comment: Prueba cambiando ```post.post_date >= NOW() + INTERVAL 6 DAY``` por ```post.post_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 6  DAY ) AND NOW()```, luego no sé lo que haces aquí ```1=1```,  sería algo como ```nombretable.nombrecolumna = 1```

Comment: También es importante el orden cuando llamas a tus columnas, primero debes llamar a tus columnas de la tabla ```wplt_posts``` llamado ```post.``` y luego ```term.```,  en tu ejemplo los mezclas, ordénalos algo como ```SELECT post.ID, post.post_title AS TITULO_POST, post.post_date AS FECHA_PUBLICACION, term.name AS CATEGORIA```

Comment: si realmente lo que quieres es eliminar los registros antiguos crea un trigger que realize la operación cada cierto tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Hola me ha funcionada de esta manera

```
SELECT post.ID, post.post_title AS TITULO_POST,term.name AS CATEGORIA, post.post_date AS FECHA_PUBLICACION, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS FECHA_ADD_7_DAY FROM wplt_posts AS post INNER JOIN wplt_term_relationships AS tax ON tax.object_id = post.ID INNER JOIN wplt_terms AS term ON term.term_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id WHERE term.slug = 'apuestas' AND post.post_date <= (SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) ORDER BY post.post_date DESC
```

He añadido un select con los parametros DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)

Comment: Hola, creo que tu respuesta quedaría mas como comentario

Comment: Hola, si me he equivocado, ya lo he corregido

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`administrador`@`localhost` EVENT `del` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 DAY 
STARTS '2021-09-30 13:50:57' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO DELETE FROM 
`tabla` WHERE `timestamp` < (CURDATE() - 90)
```

esto crea una definición para la base de datos que ejecutará un evento cada x-tiempo en una tabla donde el valor del campo sea menor del especificado.
`CREATE DEFINER`= crea la definición;
`EVENT del` da nombre al evento que se ejecutará;
`ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 DAY` donde y cada que tiempo se ejecutara;
`STARTS '2021-09-30 13:50:57' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE` comienzo del evento y no preservar tras la ejecución;
`ENABLE DO DELETE FROM tabla` activar el evento y indicar la tabla donde ejecutarlo;
 `WHERE timestamp < (CURDATE() - 90)` la condición que debe cumplirse para que la ejecución sea válida.

Comment: Por favor pulsa a editar, y agrega un poco mas de información sobre tu respuesta (Como funciona, como resuelve el problema de OP, etc.) para que otros usuarios también puedan aprender, tal y como esta es de baja calidad. ;)

Comment: listo ya esta editada